Deploy without atrifact module
INCIPIT: I wanted to ask if anyone knew how to use codebuild to publish via the (blue/green) method an ecs service with auto scaling and alb.
PROBLEM: when I try to run the stage in deploy codepipeline on ecs, I get a missing artifact error; I actually don't pass anything to it, wanting to get my image from ECR.
This service is defined in a teskDefinition.json and executed withe terraform.
TaskDefinition:
{
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "test-repo",
            "image": "xxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/nginx-repo",
            "cpu": 256,
            "memory": 512,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "containerPort": 80,
                    "hostPort": 80,
                    "protocol": "tcp"
                }
            ],
            "essential": true,
            "environment": [],
            "mountPoints": [],
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-group": "nginx-server-log-group",
                    "awslogs-region": "eu-west-1",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "nginx-server"
                }
            },
            "systemControls": []
        }
    ],
    "family": "nginx-server",
    "taskRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxx:role/nginx-ecs-task-role",
    "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:role/ngix-ecs-task-execution-role",
    "networkMode": "awsvpc",
    "volumes": [],
    "placementConstraints": [],
    "requiresCompatibilities": [
        "FARGATE"
    ],
    "cpu": "256",
    "memory": "512",
    "tags": [
        {
            "key": "Name",
            "value": "nginx-server"
        }
    ]
}

Terraform:
stage {
    name = "Deploy"

    action {
      name            = "Deploy"
      category        = "Deploy"
      owner           = "AWS"
      input_artifacts = []
      provider        = "ECS"
      version         = "1"

      configuration = {
        ClusterName = "${var.service_name}-ecs-cicd"
        ServiceName = var.service_name
        FileName    = "taskDefinition.json"
      }
    
    }
  }

I did not introduce an AppSpec, given the duplication of definitions, although I have some doubts about the correctness of this definition.
The goal is to run an ecs with the settings listed above so that it adapts itself, and recreates with blue green protocol, a new service when I launch a new pipeline.

Where is the error coming from? Terraform? CodeDeploy? Please add any relevant information to the question.

Hello, finally found the error and the solution, I didn't want to pass an artifact to codebuild but I was obliged, so I read that specifying the image file in the appspec can obviate the attempt to read the image from artifact.
Thanks anyway for being interested.

subsequent to the post I was able to solve the problem by se guendo an aws guide (link) which specified that you had to indicate which file to use to get the image to use for the build.
In seguito lascio un tutorial da seguire se si vuole effettuare un deploy completo con codepipeline CI/CD AWS

It is nice for all visitors here if your answer is completely in English. Please edit it and  translate it yourself.
